# Cannot make return satement for a java method in Android

Tags: java, android, syntax, field, return-value

In the method below the compiler does not let me return the String variable in a return statement.  If I change the local variable to a class field for the activity the error goes away.  However I wanted to just return the String I got from the image cursor.  What is the problem here?  If it is not possible to do this, why is it not possible?

I would rather not use a global field variable for the class as the return variable.  Was more interested in just getting the string information from the cursor and returning that string when I call the method inside of another method like inside of oncreate.

```
     public String checkCursor(){
        if(!filename.equals("234")){

        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE};
        String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "='" + filename +"'";

        imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,    proj, selection, null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID );
        if( imageCursor != null ){
            if( imageCursor.moveToFirst() ){

       String testString = (String) imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PRIVATE));

            }
        }

        }
        return testString;

        }
```

Comment: Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `testString` is not defined in the scope where it is returned. It should be defined in the "outer scope" (the scope of the method) and not the scope of the `if` condition.

```
     public String checkCursor(){
        String testString = null; 
       // ^^      ^^   
       //note the declaration of testString here!
        if(!filename.equals("234")){

        String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE};
        String selection = MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA + "='" + filename +"'";

        imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,    proj, selection, null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID );
        if( imageCursor != null ){
            if( imageCursor.moveToFirst() ){

       testString = (String) imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PRIVATE));

            }
        }

        }
        return testString;

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are declaring and initializing `testString` inside `if` so if the condition `imageCursor != null` or `imageCursor.moveToFirst()` evaluates to false then `testString` will not be available at all.

So use it like this :

```
imageCursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,    proj, selection, null, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID );
String testString = null;
if( imageCursor != null ){
   if( imageCursor.moveToFirst() ){
       testString = (String) imageCursor.getString(imageCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PRIVATE));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you declare testString in the if statement, and it may be undeclared when you want to return it.